# How can I get all the property names of a GTK Container?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3

I'd like to know all the property names of a GTK.Container, then I could get/set them with [child_get_property method](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkcontainer.html#method-gtkcontainer--child-get-property).

I didn't find a list of all the properties. How could I know those properties in Python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in function dir().

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__'...]


>>> dir(gtk.Container)
```

Also, you could use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) module

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(gtk.Container)
```

Comment: Thanks. Really good answer! But in my code I'm doing this and it's working: stack.child_set_property(vbox, "icon-name", "gtk-home"), but I can't find "icon-name" in the property names for Gtk.Stack or Gtk.Box() Thanks in advance :)